# Tire slash or blowout on 2005 Corvette

Tags: tires

My dad is convinced someone slashed his tire at work, but I think this could be a blowout.  Is there any way to tell the difference from looking at the tire?

Does this look like a slash or a blowout, or something else possibly?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks like stone damage to me - I think if it was deliberate it'd be a much cleaner cut, and wouldn't have the scuffs and marks around - I'd say it has done a fair few miles between the initial damage and it finally failing.

Comment: Agreed, or damage from the tyre coming into contact the a kerb or pot hole whilst in motion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Just curious, what characteristics of the hole lead you to this conclusion?

Comment: A knife cut would be more defined and crisp - not jagged.  Also, there's no way the tire would just do this from normal wear.  A "blow out" would never look like this.  Assuming I'm looking at the direction of travel correctly, you can see how the tire may have rotated down onto something sharp.  Put a sharp rock on the ground next to it and roll the car forward to visualize it.

Comment: as @JPhi1618 says, it's the raggedy edges that give it away, and also the scuff mark you can see just above the edge of the 'N', which suggest that the thing that caused the damage was irregular - therefore most likely a stone (flint, in particular, can be very sharp) rather than a neat, flat, straight blade